# How can I find if a substring is present in a string or not without using find() function?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, find, time-complexity

How can I find if a substring is present in a string or not without using find() function? Is there any efficient way to find the substring than using find() function?
`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int isSubstring(string s1, string s2)
{
     int M = s1.length();
     int N = s2.length();
     for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) {
          int j;
      for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        if (s2[i + j] != s1[j])
            break;

      if (j == M)
        return i;
     }

     return -1;
}

int main()
{
     string s1 = "for";
     string s2 = "geeksforgeeks";
     int res = isSubstring(s1, s2);
     if (res == -1)
    cout << "Not present";
     else
    cout << "Present at index " << res;
     return 0;
}
```

//I found this code on Geeks for geeks but its time complexity is O(M*(N-M)). Can it be reduced?

Comment: Please take some time to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) The geekforgeeks site has a very bad reputation around here, for teaching bad habits, bad code, and sometimes even invalid code.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and then *never* include that header again and you should probably also stop learning from whatever source told you to do that. See also [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Why would you want to not just use `.find()`?

Comment: You could use a regex.

Answer (score -1):

You could of course iterate over
one string and compare every possible substring with the substring you search for.

**BUT** it is in general better to use methods from the STL because they are well-tested and in most cases faster than your own implementation.